# MAMP php includes

Tags: php, mamp

I'm not a php developer but I'm fiddling with MAMP. I've installed MAMP and my php include() calls aren't working.

```
[13-Jul-2010 19:23:30] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mt_sandbox/php/') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mt_sandbox/php/email/owner_emails.php on line 5
```

As you can see there, I was trying to edit my php.ini file to use a second include path to the 'php' directory of my project 'mt_sandbox'.

Here are the exact includes

```
require_once("Mail.php") or die ('php load error for Mail.php');

require_once('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mt_sandbox/php/email/email_manager.php') or die ('php load error for email/email_manager.php');
```

The die messages aren't firing because I'm getting the PHP Fatal error.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I get setup to use includes in my scripts?

Comment: Can you post the exact include() call.

Comment: Does your '1' file exist? Seems odd to require a file named '1'.

Comment: I don't know what that '1' is. I'm not requiring a '1' file.

Here are the exact includes:

require_once("Mail.php") or die ('php load error for Mail.php'); 
 
require_once('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mt_sandbox/php/email/email_manager.php') or die ('php load error for email/email_manager.php');

Comment: I'm still stuck on this.

PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mt_sandbox/php/email/owner_emails.php on line 3

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this same issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion. Considering how old your post is I assume you have solved this, but figure an answer may be useful for others searching.

When installing pear extensions for MAMP make sure to run your commands using the pear package in MAMP. If pear is already installed outside of MAMP and you execute

```
pear install -a Mail
```

This will fire off the wrong pear function. Executing this will tell you which pear function you are using.

```
which pear
```

For me it was in /opt/local/bin/pear

To use the MAMP pear function I navigated into this directory '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin' and used this command

```
./pear install -a Mail
```

This fired the pear command in MAMP and installed the package for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path to the file you're including

Comment: I do want to deploy this to production when I'm done. Won't I have to manually tweak all the include paths if I use an absolute path?

Comment: Well, the a relative path would be better ;-) Are you absolutely sure the files exist where you expect them to?

Comment: I'm trying to include 2 files. The first is the Pear Mail.php file. The second is one of my own. Neither is getting included and I definitely have the right url to my file because it is sitting in the same directory as the one I'm pulling up in the browser.